# condition sample in "iOS threading programming guide"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, conditional-statements

When reading "iOS threading programming guide", I got confused with the sample code in section "Using Conditions".

Look at **Listing 4-3** and **Listing 4-4** which are used to demonstrate the use of NSCondition class. If a thread starts waiting for the condition using 4-3, and then the second thread tries to signal the condition using 4-4. Since the condition is being locked by the first thread, is there a chance for the second thread signal the condition? If no, isn't it like a deadlock?

Forgive me if this is a silly question :-)

Here's the sample Apple provided on how to use Cocoa condition:

**Listing 4-3** Using a Cocoa condition

```
[cocoaCondition lock];
while (timeToDoWork <= 0)
    [cocoaCondition wait];
timeToDoWork--;
// Do real work here.

[cocoaCondition unlock];
```

**Listing 4-4** Signaling a Cocoa condition

```
[cocoaCondition lock];
timeToDoWork++;
[cocoaCondition signal];
[cocoaCondition unlock];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first thread calls wait it relinquishes the synchronization of the lock. When the second thread calls signal the first thread can wake and will resume when the second thread unlocks its lock. At that time, the first thread regains its synchronization of the lock and can proceed safely.